# AWS AppSync Lambda authoriser always results in "Error: Request failed with status code 401"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I am currently playing around a bit with AWS AppSync and I am trying to use the Lambda authoriser feature to do some custom auth for the GraphQL API.

I have the Lambda function set up with the correct resource-based policy to allow AppSync to invoke the function and I have AppSync's `Default authorization mode` set to invoke my Lambda.

This is my lambda code:

```
exports.handler = (event) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
  const response = {
    isAuthorized: true,
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  return response;
};
```

Now I am facing the issue that the Lambda authoriser is always giving me the following error when I attempt to run a GraphQL quarry:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 401
```

After debugging this problem for two hours I can say the following things:

- The GraphQL endpoint is working fine, because if I set the `Default authorization mode` to `API key` or `Amazon cognito user pool` without changing anything else my Query executes successfully.
- The lambda function is definitely being invoked whenever I make a request to the API and the lambda also receives the correct event from AppSync.
- The Lambda returns `{"isAuthorized":true}` which means no `Authorization Token` would result in a `401`.

So as far as I can tell everything is as it should but I am still getting the `401` no matter what I do and im getting pretty frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some very frustrating debugging I finally figured out that the problem was the Lambda handler function. As it turns out a Node.js lambda handlers should be async.

So changing the lambda to the following code fixes the issue:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
    const response = {
        isAuthorized: true,
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    return response;
};
```

I didn't know this, since until no I only used Python for Lambdas, and the problem was hard to spot since the `console.log`'s where still running correctly so I though the function was returning the correct data where as in fact it was returning `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you receive an `Error: Request failed with status code 401` in your `AWS AppSync Console` and you were using `Lambda Authorizer` as your **custom Authorizer** for your API. Irrespective of what are the frameworks you used to create the Infrastructure i.e., `CDK or SAM or Serverless Framework`. Check whether you have added these correctly for your `Lanbda Authorizer`

- Check you have added proper policystatement to your Lambda Authorizer
- Check you have added permission for your `Lambda Authorizer` to your `API`
  **Eg:**
  If you are using `AWS CDK` to create all your AppSync and Lambda Authorizer, Add these two things to solve the above error

```html
    lambdaAuth.addToRolePolicy("your policy statement"),
    lambdaAuth.addPermission("appsync",{
     principal:  new ServicePrincipal("appsync.amazonaws.com"),
     action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    })
```